# How to block traffic to specific subdomain in OpenVPN?

Tags: linux, centos, iptables, firewall, openvpn

I have an OpenVPN server with some vpn clients and I want to block access to this subdomain for all of the clients : teamspeak.site.com
Is there any way to achieve this with OpenVPN configuration? If not , How about iptables rules ? I first tried to use the hosts file but it seems OpenVPN doesn't consider the file . Here is my OpenVPN config :

```
port 1194 #- port
proto udp #- protocol
dev tun
tun-mtu 1500
tun-mtu-extra 32
mssfix 1450
reneg-sec 0
ca /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/server.key
dh /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/dh1024.pem
#plugin /usr/lib64/openvpn/plugin/lib/openvpn-auth-pam.so /etc/pam.d/login #- Comment this line if you are using FreeRADIUS
#plugin /etc/openvpn/radiusplugin.so /etc/openvpn/radiusplugin.cnf #- Uncomment this line if you are using FreeRADIUS
client-cert-not-required
username-as-common-name
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
keepalive 5 30
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
status 1194.log
verb 3
```

Comment: Please add your OpenVPN configuration to the question.

Comment: I added the OpenVPN server.conf values to the question .

Comment: any help would be appreciated here .

Answer (score 1):

You can try an iptables rule as follows:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -d <IP of teamspeak.site.com> -j REJECT
```

This will reject any connection attempt coming in via tun0 that is destined to `teamspeak.site.com`.

You need to resolve the domain IP addresses beforehand.

Comment: what if that IP is cloudflare IP ? Is there any way to just block that subdomain without blocking the IP ?

Comment: In that case you need to set up your own DNS server, force your VPN users to that DNS service and then configure the DNS server to not answer to DNS queries about `teamspeak.com`.

Comment: Can you please introduce the best tool to set up my own DNS server and also by forcing my own DNS service , do you mean this parameter in OpenVPN config file ? push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"

Comment: Sorry, this is way too broad topic to be addressed here. If I were you, I would hire a professional to do the setup, since there are many pitfalls on doing DNS, and without proper knowledge you might add many vulnerabilities in your system.